# aligning shapes in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I would like to draw this picture in latex

[image]

and what I have done is quite similar but I could not finish it as this one. I tried to write under each of these three shapes what are they.  I have two problems in my resulting shape:

1. it is not aligned properly as in the original one,
2. it is quite big and I would like for example to resize it to 0.75 or 0.50 of the big resulting size.

This is my code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,circ/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=5,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0mm}]
\node[circ,label=above right:$l_1$] (l1) at (0,-10) {};
\draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) -- (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (l1) -- (5,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (-4,-17) -- (l1);
\end{tikzpicture}
& $\longrightarrow$ 
& \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,circ/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=5,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0mm}]
\node[circ,label=above right:$l_2$] (l2) at (0,-10) {};
\draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) -- (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (l2) -- (5,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (-4,-17) -- (l2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{(a) An exchanging of the node label $l_1 \rightarrow l_2$} \\
\\

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,circ/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=5,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0mm}]
\node[circ,label=above right:$l_1$] (l1) at (0,-10) {};
\node[circ,label=above right:$l_2$] (l2) at (0,-17) {};
\draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) -- (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (l1) -- (7,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (l1) -- (-7,-17) -- (-4,-17) -- (l1) -- (l2) -- (4,-24) -- (-4,-24) -- (l2);
\end{tikzpicture}
& $\longrightarrow$ 
& \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,circ/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=5,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0mm}]
\node[circ,label=above right:$l_1$] (l1) at (0,-10) {};
\draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) -- (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (l1) -- (5,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (-4,-17) -- (l1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{(b) Deleting the node labeled $l_2 \rightarrow \wedge $} \\
\\

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,circ/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=5,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0mm}]
\node[circ,label=above right:$l_1$] (l1) at (0,-10) {};
\draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) -- (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (l1) -- (5,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (-4,-17) -- (l1);
\end{tikzpicture}
& $\longrightarrow$ 
& \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,circ/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=5,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0mm}]
\node[circ,label=above right:$l_1$] (l1) at (0,-10) {};
\node[circ,label=above right:$l_2$] (l2) at (0,-17) {};
\draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) -- (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (l1) -- (7,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (l1) -- (-7,-17) -- (-4,-17) -- (l1) -- (l2) -- (4,-24) -- (-4,-24) -- (l2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{(c) Inserting a node labeled  $l_2$ as the child of the node labeled $l_1 ( \wedge \rightarrow l_2)$} \\
 &  & 
\end{tabular}

\caption{TE}
\end{figure}
```

Look at my result

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main thing you need to do is specify a baseline for your figures.  Fortunately you label the relevant points, so you can just add, e.g.

```
baseline=(l1)
```

to the `tikzpicture` options.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \newcommand{\mybigstrut}{\rule{0pt}{5ex}}
  \newcommand{\mycaption}[1]{\multicolumn{3}{l}{\mybigstrut #1}}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,circ/.style={circle,draw,
      minimum width=5,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0mm},baseline=(l1)]
      \node[circ,label=above right:$l_1$] (l1) at (0,-10) {};
      \draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) --
      (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
      \draw (0,-3) -- (l1) -- (5,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (4,-17) --
      (-4,-17) -- (l1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &$\Longrightarrow$
    &\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,circ/.style={circle,draw,
      minimum width=5,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0mm},baseline=(l2)]
      \node[circ,label=above right:$l_2$] (l2) at (0,-10) {};
      \draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) --
      (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
      \draw (0,-3) -- (l2) -- (5,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (4,-17) --
      (-4,-17) -- (l2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \\
    \mycaption{(a) An exchanging of the node label $l_1 \rightarrow
    l_2$} \\[3ex]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,circ/.style={circle,draw,
      minimum width=5,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0mm},baseline=(l1)]
      \node[circ,label=above right:$l_1$] (l1) at (0,-10) {};
      \node[circ,label=above right:$l_2$] (l2) at (0,-17) {};
      \draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) --
      (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
      \draw (0,-3) -- (l1) -- (7,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (l1) -- (-7,-17)
      -- (-4,-17) -- (l1) -- (l2) -- (4,-24) -- (-4,-24) -- (l2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &$\Longrightarrow$
    &\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,circ/.style={circle,draw,
      minimum width=5,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0mm},baseline=(l1)]
      \node[circ,label=above right:$l_1$] (l1) at (0,-10) {};
      \draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) --
      (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
      \draw (0,-3) -- (l1) -- (5,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (4,-17) --
      (-4,-17) -- (l1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \\
    \mycaption{(b) Deleting the node labeled $l_2 \rightarrow \wedge $} \\[3ex]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,circ/.style={circle,draw,
      minimum width=5,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0mm},baseline=(l1)]
      \node[circ,label=above right:$l_1$] (l1) at (0,-10) {};
      \draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) --
      (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
      \draw (0,-3) -- (l1) -- (5,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (4,-17) --
      (-4,-17) -- (l1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &$\Longrightarrow$
    &\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,circ/.style={circle,draw,
      minimum width=5,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0mm},baseline=(l1)]
      \node[circ,label=above right:$l_1$] (l1) at (0,-10) {};
      \node[circ,label=above right:$l_2$] (l2) at (0,-17) {};
      \draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) --
      (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
      \draw (0,-3) -- (l1) -- (7,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (l1) -- (-7,-17)
      -- (-4,-17) -- (l1) -- (l2) -- (4,-24) -- (-4,-24) -- (l2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \\
    \mycaption{(c) Inserting a node labeled  $l_2$ as the child of the
    node labeled $l_1 ( \wedge \rightarrow l_2)$} \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{TE}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Additionally you need some extra vertical space between the figures and the text.  I have done this by adding in invisible rule, introduced a short command to set the texts the way you specified, and adding some extra vertical space via the optional argument to `\\`.  Alternatively have a look at the what the [`tikz` documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en) has to say about establishing a bounding box for diagrams.

For the resizing, just change the `scale` factors on each diagram.

Just as introduced a common macro for the texts, you can see some `tikz` options uniformly for all the pictures via `\tikzset`, e.g.

```
  \tikzset{circ/.style={circle,draw,
  minimum width=5,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0mm}}
```

placed just before the `\centering` command in your code, will enable you to remove this styling from the code for each individual picture.

Comment: It is better now, thank you, I tried to play on scales but this will make the shape over the text {l1, l2}, so I decided to leave it as it is. If there is a way to resize the figure at once this might be a better solution than rescaling the factors for each diagram.

Comment: You can use `\scalebox` from the graphicx package, either (1) wrapped around each diagram, or (2) by just have one cell on each row and putting the scalebox around all the elements in that row at once.  In (2) you will loose the alignment of the horizontal arrows.

Answer (score 4):

Slightly different approach as in Andrew Swann answer:

- positioning of image is determined by `baseline`
- arrows are drawn by `tikz`
- for space between rows with subtitle is used `addlinespace` from ackage `booktabs`
- `circ` style is defined only ones

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \tikzset{baseline,
          x = 0.2cm, 
          y = 0.2cm,
circ/.style = {circle, draw, minimum width=5,
               inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm}
            }
\begin{tabular}{lcl}  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circ,label=above right:$l_1$] (l1) at (0,-10) {};
\draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) -- (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (l1) -- (5,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (-4,-17) -- (l1);
\end{tikzpicture}
& \tikz[baseline=2cm]{\draw[semithick, double distance=2pt,
              arrows={-{Stealth[length=5mm]}}] (0,0) -- + (5,0);}
& \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\node[circ,label=above right:$l_2$] (l2) at (0,-10) {};
\draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) -- (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (l2) -- (5,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (-4,-17) -- (l2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{l}{(a) An exchanging of the node label $l_1 \rightarrow l_2$} \\

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circ,label=above right:$l_1$] (l1) at (0,-10) {};
\node[circ,label=above right:$l_2$] (l2) at (0,-17) {};
\draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) -- (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (l1) -- (7,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (l1) -- (-7,-17) -- (-4,-17) -- (l1) -- (l2) -- (4,-24) -- (-4,-24) -- (l2);
\end{tikzpicture}
& \tikz[baseline=2cm]{\draw[semithick, double distance=2pt,
              arrows={-{Stealth[length=5mm]}}] (0,0) -- + (5,0);}
& \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circ,label=above right:$l_1$] (l1) at (0,-10) {};
\draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) -- (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (l1) -- (5,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (-4,-17) -- (l1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{l}{(b) Deleting the node labeled $l_2 \rightarrow \wedge $} \\

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circ,label=above right:$l_1$] (l1) at (0,-10) {};
\draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) -- (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (l1) -- (5,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (-4,-17) -- (l1);
\end{tikzpicture}
& \tikz[baseline=2cm]{\draw[semithick, double distance=2pt,
              arrows={-{Stealth[length=5mm]}}] (0,0) -- + (5,0);}
& \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circ,label=above right:$l_1$] (l1) at (0,-10) {};
\node[circ,label=above right:$l_2$] (l2) at (0,-17) {};
\draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3) -- (-7,-10) -- (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (l1) -- (7,-17) -- (4,-17) -- (l1) -- (-7,-17) -- (-4,-17) -- (l1) -- (l2) -- (4,-24) -- (-4,-24) -- (l2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{l}{(c) Inserting the node labeled  $l_2$ as the child 
                       of the node labeled $l_1 ( \wedge \rightarrow l_2)$} \\
 &  &
\end{tabular}

\caption{TE}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer, nice introduction of 'booktabs' package .. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @lol745, I eddit my answer. Now the `scale` of each `tikzpicture` is  centralised by `x=0.2cm, y=0.2cm` in common `tikzset`.